# RecyclerView: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position - using getFilter()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have Recycler View with list of Countries. On top of Recycler there is also Search View which is used to filtering countries and find without scrolling long list.
When I am typing in search and parallelly scrolling over list sometimes there is Error with Inconsistency Detected.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionCountryHolder{a35d5ed position=54 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{1c30d63 VFED..... ......ID 0,410-1440,1899 #7f0a0028 app:id/SymbolRecyclerView}... androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5974)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6158)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
```

or this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 14(offset:14).state:48 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{6df376e VFED..... ........ 0,410-1440,1899 #7f0a0028 app:id/SymbolRecyclerView}....
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6183)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:345)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
```

or this in GooglePLay test:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{5ae0fff VFED..... ......ID 0,322-1080,1561 #7f0a0028 app:id/SymbolRecyclerView}....
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:3051)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onChanged(RecyclerView.java:5536)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:12253)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:7354)
    at RecyclerView_Adapter$getFilter$1.publishResults(RecyclerView_Adapter.kt:109)
```

I was googling about this and I found that I need to use notifyDataSetChanged() function and use temporary list for modyfing while searching but seems it is proper in my code. Can anybody help with fix ?
Below is my RecyclerView_Adapter code:

```
class RecyclerView_Adapter(private var countryList: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    var countryFilterList = ArrayList<String>()
    lateinit var mcontext: Context
    class CountryHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    init {
        countryFilterList = countryList
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val countryListView =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, parent, false)
        val sch = CountryHolder(countryListView)
        mcontext = parent.context
        return sch
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countryFilterList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.Symbol.text = countryFilterList[position]
    }


    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val charSearch = constraint.toString()
                if (charSearch.isEmpty()) {
                    countryFilterList = countryList
                } else {
                    val resultList1 = ArrayList<String>()
                    for (row in countryList) {
                        if (row.contains(charSearch)) {
                            resultList1.add(row)
                        }
                    }
                    countryFilterList = ArrayList(resultList1.distinct())
                }
                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = countryFilterList
                return filterResults
            }

            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                countryFilterList = results?.values as ArrayList<String>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please note that when performing notifyDataSetChanged() RecycleView should not be in scrolling mode.

Comment: @Herry I was reading this article: https://parithi.com/recyclerview-indexoutofboundsexception-inconsistency-detected-1fc71a5834f2. There is written that thise option is possible but not recomended: "Disable the scrolling on the recycler view when the data is being updated by overriding the onTouch.". Is this what You mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Alternative solution.

Create Flowable from Original list

```
val countryListFlowable = Flowable.fromArray(countryList)

val consumer = Consumer<ArrayList<String>> {
   //Here Search result will come as it
   mAdapterRecycleView.updateList(it)

}

val disposableSearch = countryListFlowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).map { t: ArrayList<String> ->
                            t.filter {countryName: String ->
                                var isFound=false
                                if (countryName.contains(charSearch)) {
                             isFound = true
                        }
                                isFound
                            }
                        }.subscribe(consumer)
```

Your Adapter will have this method

```
fun updateList(list: ArrayList<String):  {
        countryFilterList = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()

       }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution and let You known.